# Is there a way to disavow all backlinks for a single post page?

Tags: google-search-console

A single internal post page has recieved 100's of backlinks from unrelated sites (pingbacks, comment spam).

Now instead of going through every single domain/page to disavow I'd like to disavow all links that are pointing towards that specific url. It's been already 404, but I'm certain the spam is still causing SEO damage, penalization from google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

404s do not pass Page Authority. However, if your site was penalized, then you need to submit a disavow list.

You can get a list of all the domains from Google Search Console -> Links - Top Linked pages - externally. Click the page you want to disavow links for, and then export the data.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en for more info on how to submit a disavow list.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not seeing the page there though, but when I google the URL, I get 100's of results of the page posted to random blog comments.

Comment: How long have you managed the GSC property? Information may take 2-3 days to show up for new properties. Another possibility is that it's removed, as it's a 404, depends on how long it's been a 404.

Comment: 404'd it a couple of hours ago. The spam links have been posted during the last 4 months. None during the last week.

Comment: How long since you verified the GSC property?

Comment: The 404 should mean those links will be ignored and disavows are not needed. It's most likely those sorts of links will be ignored anyhow. If you have been given a manual link penalty then you will see a message in your Search Console.